# can't change a simple functional excel macro to similar as function

Tags: excel, vba, count, cell

I'm totally new at VBA and Macros on excel. I had a macro that some nice guy posted and it's working perfectly, but I need it as a function so I was trying and trying but I am frankly completely lost. I will really appreciate your help. First, the Macros and last the function I thought I was doing well but no good results yet. By the way, context: it's a macro to count cells by colors with conditional formatting (no formula!!)  in excel.

```
Sub DisplayColorCount()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim CountRange As Range
    Dim ColorRange As Range
    Dim xBackColor As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "dptutorials"
    Set CountRange = Application.Selection
    Set CountRange = Application.InputBox("Count Range :", xTitleId, CountRange.Address, Type:=8)
    Set ColorRange = Application.InputBox("Color Range(single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set ColorRange = ColorRange.Range("A1")
    xReturn = 0
    For Each Rng In CountRange
        qqq = Rng.Value
        xxx = Rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        If Rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = ColorRange.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color Then
            xBackColor = xBackColor + 1
        End If
    Next
    ActiveCell.Value = xBackColor
End Sub
```

---

```
Function DisplayColorCount2(CountRange As Range, ColorRange As Range)
    Dim Rng As Range
    'Dim CountRange As Range
    'Dim ColorRange As Range
    Dim xBackColor As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    'xTitleId = "dptutorials"
    'Set CountRange = Application.Selection
    'Set CountRange = Application.InputBox("Count Range :", xTitleId, CountRange.Address, Type:=8)
    'Set ColorRange = Application.InputBox("Color Range(single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    'Set ColorRange = ColorRange.Range("A1")
    xReturn = 0
    For Each Rng In CountRange
        qqq = Rng.Value
        xxx = Rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        If Rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = ColorRange.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color Then
            xBackColor = xBackColor + 1
        End If
    Next
    DisplayColorCount2 = xBackColor
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately `DisplayFormat` does not work in a user-defined function (called from a worksheet cell)

Comment: Ouch ... that explains a lot. Thanks Tim.